# Read from file before specific character in java

Tags: java

How to read from file line before specific character? For example I have such line:

```
"Hello world !I am Nika."
```

How can I read text before `!`?
I have tried with `BufferedReader` class method `ReadLine`, but it reads whole line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)** function like this:

```
String str = "Hello world !I am Nika.";
String neededStr = str.split("!")[0];
System.out.println(neededStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole line and use `String.split()`

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from file and split it using `split()`

```
        String str = "Hello world !I am Nika.";
        String neededStr = str.split("!")[0];
        System.out.println(neededStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring() and indexOf() in combination. You first obtain the index of exclamation mark and then get the substring from the start position to the index of exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. It should be something like
String str = input.nextLine.substring (indexof ("character")+1);

Comment: I'm from phone so case is not correct. But this idea should work